# validates uniqueness: { scope: [:foobar] } not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, sidekiq

I have a model that has a uniqueness validation on it something like:

```
class CurriculumRequirement < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :student

  belongs_to :curriculum_sequence

  validates :student_id,
    uniqueness: { scope: [:curriculum_sequence_id] }
end
```

The problem is that somehow duplicate records are being inserted into my database despite this validation. The place in which adding these records happens in a sidekiq background worker:

`student.curriculum_requirements.where(curriculum_sequence: sequence).first_or_create`

I *think* that what is happening is that 2 or more workers are executing the same code, and saving the record. Is there a way to put a lock or something on this record so that I don't get duplicates?

Comment: `sidekiq background worker` yes, this happens when it works in a few threads. You should include some locker, or setup sidekiq to work in one thread.

Comment: In case of locker you could do `Model.transaction { ... }` [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html). Let me khow if it helps, i post it as an answer.

Comment: There are also some info on [sidekiq docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware) but i think you can avoid this. Transaction should be enough.

Comment: Why don't use a database unique constraint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails cannot guarantee uniqueness.  You need to create a unique index on the table on `[curriculum_sequence_id, student_id]` in the database.

Comment: Creating an index of this kind with already populated duplicated data might lead into trouble. Please see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752366/rails-unique-index-on-multiple-columns-fails-sqlite3